# Getting unique record from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a problem in mysql. I need to fetch certain sets of records from a table that has the following data.

[image]

Let me brief you guys about the table. every primary item has a similar item and that similar item has a size.

but we have to show unique items from the above table having least size.

for example.. primary item is A and it's corresponding item in X and X is also primary and it's similar item in A but X also has a similar item P so A,X,P all are similar and in these the item with least size is P with size 4 so we have fetch P from the table with a query.

Furthermore the records are 1-M and all primary item as similar items and all similar items exits in the primary field in the database. And this table contain nearly 3 lacs record for fetching and looping one records at a time will not work..

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks
Jawed Shamshedi

Comment: P also has similar item - Q, then the size should be 8. Is it correct?

Comment: can you show the table schema ?

Comment: @Devart -- Yes P has similar item Q so Q should be fetched with query as it came only one in the db

Comment: @sakhunzai -  The table schema is given below.

CREATE TABLE `similar_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Stock` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `SimilarStock` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ItemSize` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT '0.00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: To which column does `size` belong ?

Comment: It looks like a hierarchy, but MySQL has no hierarchy support. So, you can do it in the application.

Comment: @Devart- Can you please explain a bit what do you means by Hierarchy and since the records are 3 lacs in this table I can't go for fetching the data and looping the data and it will take much time.. Any other option???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE similar_test ( id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
Stock varchar(20) NOT NULL, SimilarStock varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
ItemSize decimal(18,2) DEFAULT '0.00' ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

please check this : I am considering for 1 level depth :

```
select * , s.ItemSize as minSize from similar_test as p
 join similar_test a s on s.Stock= p.SimilarStock
 where p.Sock='A'
 order by  s.itemSize 
 limit 1
```

If that is not addressing you questions as you said in comments the other options are :

a. create another table which will hold PRE- calculated values are desired

b. Write a stored procedure to go through the item list upto N-levels as N is unspecified
    in this case (as I suspected)

c. Do the sorting and grouping in PHP/or any other language you are using

this might also help you [hierarchical data](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)
regards

Comment: @sakhunzai- It running fine for A but we have to run this query in general over the whole table and we don't know which item is similar to how many items and till what depth.. By the way, thanks for your effort and time